# In VIM: How to close a file/buffer among many opened files

Tags: file, vim, command, buffer

In vim, command "e" is used to open a file to a buffer: but how to close a file/buffer without quiting vim or disable all vimrc settings?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several commands, and their use depends on how aggresively you want those buffer to vanish.

You can use `:close` or `:quit` to remove the current window. As long as you have other split windows / tab pages, this will not close Vim. The buffer is still in Vim's internal buffer list (`:ls` still shows it). The `'hidden'` option also influences this.

If you really want to get rid of the buffer, `:bdelete` does that; you can conveniently pass it a buffer number of its filespec. `:bunload` also frees the memory and resources; this may be useful if it's been a exceptionally large file, but I don't usually need it.

Answer (score 3):

I use `:bw` to wipe-out everything related to a buffer (identified by its name or its internal number). The documentation recommends to use `:bd` to just delete buffer information. (I must admit I don't see the point about keeping some information, and I've never observed any troubles in using `:bw` in decades of intensive use of Vim)